# Count number of rows before date per id

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm not sure how else to explain it other than the title.  I'm basically trying to get the number of rows per id before the date on that specific row.  I've tried a bunch of things and scoured the internet to no avail.  Please help!

**Before**

```
id  date  
1   3/3/2015  
2   3/27/2015  
2   4/15/2015  
2   5/1/2015  
3   3/7/2015  
3   5/17/2015  
3   7/9/2015  
3   7/19/2015
```

**After**

```
id  date        count
1   3/3/2015    0
2   3/27/2015   0
2   4/15/2015   1
2   5/1/2015    2
3   3/7/2015    0
3   5/17/2015   1
3   7/9/2015    2
3   7/19/2015   3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
-1 + row_number() over (partition by id order by date)
```